# How do i make a new chart by pressing a button (chart.js)?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I was wondering if it's possible to go from a bar to a pie-chart by pressing a button?

```
<script>        
var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Miljoner ton',
            data: [56.38, 59.3, 61.81, 58.83, 52.32, 66.86],
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(124,181,236)'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }

            }]
        }
    }
});

function adddata() {

    myChart.data.datasets[0].data[7] = 14;
    myChart.data.labels[7] = "Newly added";

    myChart.update();

}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking on how to listen to keyboard input or are you asking how to create another chart?

Comment: You could just implement both charts and then give a hidden class with css when you click the button?

Comment: You would need to select data into an dataprovider array, and register on('click') events for two buttons, html('') clear the holder, and then make chart for that element, that responds to needed chart type

Answer (score 2):

Follow the perfect link https://codepen.io/mateegojra/pen/GXVOap

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("barChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// We are only changing the chart type, so let's make that a global variable along with the chart object:
var chartType = 'bar';
var myBarChart;

// Global Options:
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'grey';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;

var data = {
  labels: ["2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "UFO Sightings",
    fill: true,
    lineTension: 0.1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.4)",
    borderColor: "green", // The main line color
    borderCapStyle: 'square',
    pointBorderColor: "white",
    pointBackgroundColor: "green",
    pointBorderWidth: 1,
    pointHoverRadius: 8,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "yellow",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "green",
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 4,
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    data: [10, 13, 17, 12, 30, 47, 60, 120, 230, 300, 310, 400],
    spanGaps: true,
  }]
};

// Notice the scaleLabel at the same level as Ticks
var options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    display: true,
    text: 'I want to believe !',
    position: 'bottom'
  }
};


// We add an init function down here after the chart options are declared.

init();

function init() {
  // Chart declaration:
  myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: chartType,
    data: data,
    options: options
  });
}

function toggleChart() {
  //destroy chart:
  myBarChart.destroy();
  //change chart type: 
  this.chartType = (this.chartType == 'bar') ? 'line' : 'bar';
  //restart chart:
  init();
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}
.as-console-wrapper{display: none !important }
#barChart{
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-radius: 6px;
/*   Check out the fancy shadow  on this one */

}

.btn{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<!--
THe post that goes with this pen:
https://codepen.io/k3no/post/learning-by-example-getting-started-with-chart-js 
-->

<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
<!--       Chart.js Canvas Tag -->
      <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>    
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>    
    <div class="col-md-10"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" onclick="toggleChart();">Toggle Chart </button></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: scroll down the result window to view **toggle button for changing chart type**

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in your onclick function:

```
myChart.type = "pie";
myChart.update();
```